# How to receive temperature and battery charge of Beacons using Altbeacons

Tags: java, android, ibeacon, altbeacon

I have to monitor temperature and battery status of beacons in android using Altbeacon (without using Eddystone or other libs).
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AltBeacon format defines a one byte data byte that may be used for any manufacturer-specific purpose such as a temperature reading.  This, however, is dependent on a beacon manufacturer supporting this use of the data field.   **In theory**, with a beacon that takes the output of a hardware temperature sensor and puts it into the data field of the AltBeacon transmission, **you could get the temperature like this**:

```
long temperature = beacon.getDataFields().get(0);
```

That said, **I am unaware of any manufacturer that sends a temperature reading in the AltBeacon transmission.**  It is more common to use the data field byte for a battery level (Radius Networks' beacons do this).  That said, you could always make your own custom beacon that does this.

Full disclosure:  I work for Radius Networks.